# skipping a specific validation when using valid? in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my `Post` model, I have a couple of validations for attribute `link`

```
  validates :link, url: true, uniqueness: true
```

Now, in my controller, I would like to call:

```
@post = Post.new(link: "google.com")
@post.valid?
```

I want to check if the link is in correct format, but to skip uniqueness test. How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an `:if => :method_name` argument on validations which will cause that validation to only run if the condition in the method is true. Put whatever your condition is in that method.

Example:

```
validates :link, :uniqueness => true, :if => :validate_link_uniqueness? #Will only run if validate_link_uniqueness? returns true
validates :link, :url => true # Will always run

def validate_link_uniqueness?
  !new_record? # Insert the conditions that return true if uniqueness should be validated
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if there is an error for that field:

```
@post.errors[:link].blank?
```

Comment: Thanks Milan. This is an interesting option, but ideally, I would not like Rails to through the error.